# Port GLSL matrix to GLSL ES

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I have the following code in a standard OpenGL shader:

```
vec3 I4, C1, A0, G5;
mat3 yuv_weighted;

vec4 i4 = yuv_weighted[0] * mat4x3(I4, C1, A0, G5);
```

How can I convert it to OpenGL ES 2.0, which does not support rectangular matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
vec3 I4, C1, A0, G5;
mat3 yuv_weighted;

vec4 i4 = vec4(dot(yuv_weighted[0], I4), dot(yuv_weighted[0], C1),
               dot(yuv_weighted[0], A0), dot(yuv_weighted[0], G5));
```

Or even

```
vec4 i4 = vec4(yuv_weighted[0]*mat3(I4, C1, A0), dot(yuv_weighted[0], G5));
```

though the first version may be more efficient (not sure).